# Firestore email attachments

Tags: firebase, file-upload, google-cloud-firestore

Basically what I'm looking for is the ability to send emails with attachments (multiple attachments) to my email. My current approach is to get files and convert them to the dataUri then save email skeleton to firestore. Then I have a cloud function that fires onSave and sends the email to my email using Gmail transporter and after I delete the record from firestore so there is no persistent saving to a database. This approach works but its very limited because I can't send files which sum exceeding 1 MB and that's sucks.

Can anyone point me the best way to get similar behaviour but be able to send larger files? I would like to send up to 5 files with 3mb per file if its possible.

P.S.
I've enabled blaze plan

---

Im not sure whats wrong here.. Im unable to send an email.

Yeah, right I forgot about HTTPS functions. But I've one problem Im unable to send an email and Im not sure what's wrong.

```html
exports.sendEmaill = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
  }

  console.log(req.body);

  return cors(req, res, () => {
    const mailOptions = parseBody(req.body);

    console.log(mailOptions);
    // return res.status(200).send(mailOptions)
    return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
      .then((info) => res.status(200).send(info))
      .catch((error) => res.status(403).send(error));
  });
});
```

With this I can fire the function
    // return res.status(200).send(mailOptions)

But as soon as I want to use mailTransport I got
`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: How about submitting the files to a Firebase HTTPS function which sends the email? This way, you don't have to temporarily store files in the database.

Comment: I got it working but actually its very slow if i put at least 1 file which is bigger than 1.5 mb in size it takes somewhere 1 minute to handle thjis request